# How to trigger events by clicking on row in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, user-interface, datatables, pysimplegui

New to the library and despite working through the DEMO code I'm struggling to prompt events by clicking directly on the table row. I can easily whip something up that allows a user to select a row, and then trigger the desired event with a button as below, but I'm not sure how to cut out the button step and have the event triggered directly from clicking on the row?

```
   layout = [[sg.Table(values=df.values.tolist(),
                            headings=df.columns.tolist(),
                            max_col_width=25,
                            auto_size_columns=True,
                            justification='right',
                            # alternating_row_color='lightblue',
                            num_rows=min(len(df), 20))],
              
              
              [sg.Button('Select Row', key='_rowselected_')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get event of clicking on table, there're two events provided

- Option `enable_click_events` for event of clicking on cell before row selected, so values[table] still keep old data for selection.
- Option `enable_events` for event of row selection, values[table] will keep the data for new selection.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")

newlist = [
    [f"Cell ({row:0>2d}, {col:0>2d})" for col in range(8)]
        for row in range(10)
]

COL_HEADINGS = ["Date", "Ref", "ID", "Owner", "Customer", "Price", "Size", "Path"]

layout = [
    [sg.Table(
        values=newlist,
        headings=COL_HEADINGS,
        max_col_width=25,
        num_rows=10,
        alternating_row_color='green',
        key='-TABLE-',
        enable_events=True,
        # enable_click_events=True,
        justification='center',
    )],
    [sg.Text("", size=(50, 1), expand_x=True, key='-Position-')]
]

window = sg.Window('Table', layout, finalize=True)
table = window['-TABLE-']
position = window['-Position-']

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif isinstance(event, tuple) and event[0:2] == ('-TABLE-', '+CICKED+'):
        # click position row, column, count from 0, -1 for headings
        row, col = event[2]
        selection = values['-TABLE-']
        # previous selected row number, not now.
        previous_select_row = selection[0] if selection else 'None'
        position.update(f'Clicked position is ({row}, {col}), and previous selected row is {previous_select_row}')

    elif event == '-TABLE-':
        # selected row number, cound from 0
        row = values[event]
        if row:
            position.update(f'Selected row is {row}')

    print(event, values)

window.close()
```